# ¿Cómo buscar por fecha en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, json, date

Estoy intentando hacer un PHP que conecte con mi base de datos e imprima en un array JSON los valores de "amount" siempre y cuando la date de la tabla de la base de datos sea la del día de hoy.

En la base de datos lo guardo con TIMESTAMP (YY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss).

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
$weekstart = $date->modify('last monday')->format('d');

$today = date('j');
$n_dayotw = $today - $weekstart;
$name = date('l');

header("Content-type: application/json");
require_once("../connect.php");
$db = new Conexion();
$dbTabla='r_water';
$user = $_GET["iduser"];
$consulta = "SELECT amount FROM $dbTabla WHERE id_user = $user AND date(date) = $today";
$result = $db->prepare($consulta);
$result->execute();

if (!$result){ 
    print "<error>Error en la consulta.</error>\n";
}else{
    $water = array();

    foreach($result as $valor){     
        $arr = array(
            'amount' => $valor['amount']);
        array_push($water, $arr);
    }

    echo json_encode($water);
}
$db=NULL;
?>
```

Todo funciona si en la consulta no le pongo el `AND ___date____..:`, pero debo hacer ese filtro de la fecha. El problema está en lo de dentro de la consulta, por lo tanto.

---

He probado esto:

```
$date_today = date('Y-m-d');
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM $dbTaula WHERE id_user = $user AND date('Y-m-d',day) = $date_today";
```

Pero no funciona bien. (day es el campo de la base de datos dónde sale la fecha (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss).

Comment: Primero pruebalo de forma estatica es decir hasle un echo a tu fecha que genera en php y llevalo a tu MYSQL,  tal ves no es el mismo formato del que esta en tu BD y siempre pon entre comillas tus variables dentro de tu consulta

Comment: Tu variable `$today` solamente es el día del mes, y eso no puedes comparlo contra una fecha format YY-mm-dd de tu base de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La fecha actual en la `Base de datos` la guardas con `now()`.
Después por más que guardes `Y-m-d` en un campo `datetime`, el *horario* queda todo en *0*, así que no habría problemas.

Answer (score 1):

**NUNCA UTILICES** un selector como **`DATE(datecolumns) = '2012-12-24'`**, esto afecta el desempeño.

Si la columna "day" es un datetime deberías usar un "=" junto con el dato a comparar:

```
SELECT * FROM [tabla]
WHERE [columna (datetime)] = [atributo (datetime)]
```

O un **BETWEEN** si es en un rango de fechas:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE columname BETWEEN '2012-12-25 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-25 23:59:59'
```

Intenta quemando las fechas, para ver si tienes resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema que estas teniendo es que al guardar la fecha con hora minutos y segundos al comparar con la fecha actual nunca va a coincidir, para solucionar esto podrías modificar tu consulta sql de la siguiente forma:

```
$dia = date("Y-m-d");
$hora_min = $dia . ' 00:00:00';
$hora_max = $dia . ' 23:59:59' ;

$consulta = "SELECT amount FROM r_water WHERE id_user = $user AND date >= $hora_min AND date <= $hora_max";
```

Otra forma sería utilizar [BETWEEN](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php):

```
$consulta = "SELECT amount FROM r_water WHERE id_user = $user AND (date BETWEEN $hora_min AND $hora_max)";
```